# saving jmeter response in array and send it other api

Tags: jmeter

I want to save values from the API response in the array, the array will contain the values from all threads in the thread group,
I tried  to add it in the post presses but the issue here is the array will be created for each thread so  it will only contain one value

so is there any way to declare the array globally
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3hES.png)

so is there any way to declare the array globally

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an array as global variable - The idea, I would think of using system.setProperty() function

In Jmeter using JSR223(groovy) you can call using props.put() function and all threads can access via props.get()

e.g:
Typical example goes like this

```
def list = []  // Default impl is ArrayList

/* Store the value to the arraylist */

props.put("variableName", list) // Stores the arrraylist using this function
props.get("variableName") // Retrieve the arrraylist using this function
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

So the options are in:

1. Either write the "codes" into a file using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) and then read it where required using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
2. Or switch to `props` shorthand instead of `vars`, but you will need to come up with a prefix/postfix like current thread/iteration number otherwise you will overwrite the propertly created by previous thread
3. Or consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins)